# Can you create a react redux store interceptor to watch a property?

Tags: reactjs, redux, state, store

Let's say i have a property in the store called `state.items.byId` each time this is updated (various parts of the application) i want to intercept the value before i'ts updated and run a function to update some properties on it before it's updated.

I don't know the terminology and i'm quite new to redux, but if someone could point me in the right direction that would be great!

I have searched and found `redux-watch` but i'm not 100% sure if this is the right approach

Comment: When using Redux the state is immutable. Meaning it always be modified through an action, in a reducer. I assume you are setting the state only in the unidirectional way as redux does. And yes redux-watch is for watching a property change. Whenever your property changes, you will be notified. 
Ex: https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-watch. Let me know if you need more explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

below shows the data flow in a redux application. View dispatches an action, the action 
  object is a blue-print telling the reducer what changes it needs to make to the store state. Any 
  change in the redux store state needs to pass through this cycle.

redux-watch provides you a subscription based mechanism notifying you **after** a property is 
  changed. If you want to intercept a property before its changed you can write a custom
  **middleware** and handle any side-effects inside it.